# Searching in "C++ Language" turns up results in "C++ Language" but listed under "C Language"

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, search

When I perform a search in [C++ Language](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2B%2B/topics), the search results are for the C++ Language, but the language is now C. Here's a [search for "hi"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=c%2B%2B&query=hi).

[image: Searching for "hi" in C++ Language]

Results in:

[image: Results]

Clicking on that "C Language" leads to the C Language page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too much URL decoding can be a bad thing, apparently.

A fix is rolling out now. Thanks for the report!