# Stack Overflow Documentation: C++ category's search bar fails to return results after multiple searches

Tags: bug, documentation

Below is some information on what I believe is a bug in the Stack Overflow Documentation site. Sorry for any lack of important information, I have very little experience with web development. If I am missing any critical information please comment and I will include it.

**Bug Description**

When using the search bar in the [C++ category on Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2B%2B/topics) it will bring you to the C category instead of the C++ category.

[image: First Search]

The first search will show results correctly but any subsequent searches you try will fail, even if you search for something that is in the C category.

[image: Second Search]

[image: C Category Topic Search]

I have not checked to see if this is only the case for the C++ category or if it extends to other categories also.

**Browser**

Google Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m

Have not tested on other browsers or versions.

**How to reproduce:**

1. Go to the C++ category of Stack Overflow Documentation ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2B%2B/topics))
2. Type "std::vector" into the search bar in the top right (By request topic)
3. This will show you the results like expected, but will also bring you to the C category which is not expected.
4. Click the search button again, it will return no search results (Even with the same "std::vector" as input).
5. Try searching for a topic that is in the "C Language" category like "Hello World", even this will return no results.

Edit: While this report is similar to another [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328850/searching-in-c-language-turns-up-results-in-c-language-but-listed-under) in that they both show C++ category searches moving to the C category, they are actually different in that it exposes another more serious issue of any subsequent searches failing (Step 4 and 5 in how to reproduce).

Comment: No repro here? ...

Comment: I was able to reproduce this, Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m on Windows 7. Oddly, in step 3, if I open a result it does take me to the C++ topic, not a C topic.

Comment: I can reproduce that. Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116 on Linux Mint.